# Linq: get articles with top vote count

Tags: c#, linq

i have a list of articles, and each article has one or more votes in a collection.
It's a entity framework collection, but i don't think that makes a lot of difference for the problem.
Navigating goes like this:

Article.Votes, where Votes is a collection of vote objects.
What i'm looking for is the Linq statement how i can find the top 5 articles with most votes.
So 1 articles has 100 votes (vote objects in the Votes collection), 3 have 90, 1 have 88, 4 have 78, etc, then i want to select the ones with 100, 90 and 88.
The article collection, btw, is not sorted on the number of votes.

Regards,
Michel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var articles = GetArticleList();
var topArticles = articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.Votes.Count).Take(5);
```

You need the descending clause so you get the highest voted articles first.

Answer (score 3):

```
var top5 = (from a in articles
       orderby a.Votes.Count descending
       select a).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var top5Articles = listOfArticles.OrderByDescending(a => a.Votes.Count).Take(5);
```

Not tested, but SHOULD work...

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Articles.OrderByDescending(pArticle => pArticle.Votes.Max(pVote => pVote.Num))
        .Take(5)
```